# QueryServiceObjectSecurity fails with access denied error

Tags: windows, winapi, service, permissions

QueryServiceObjectSecurity call is failing with access denied error, i am not quite able to figure out why. I create service and then try to update the permissions for it. Interestingly once the call fails service is created and if i reexecute code, it detects existing service and attaches handle and then this call works fine, then why it fails for the first time? I am new to windows services, is there like during first time execution, service is created but SCM db  is not updated before i query object security?

Code snippet is below

Service creation:

```
managerHandle.Attach(::OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS));
serviceHandle.Attach(::CreateService(managerHandle, serviceName, serviceDisplayName, 
                SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG | SERVICE_START | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_INTERROGATE,
                serviceType, startCode, errorControl, path,
                groupName, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));

::ChangeServiceConfig2(m_serviceHandle, SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION,  &serviceDesc);
service.Detach();
```

now after this i call function which updates the dacl for the service

```
ENSURE_STATE(!!m_serviceHandle)
CAutoPtr<PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR *> pSecurityDescriptor;
DWORD bytesNeeded = 0;
if(::QueryServiceObjectSecurity(serviceHandle, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &pSecurityDescriptor, 0, &bytesNeeded) == FALSE)
{
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access rights for system services are described in the MSDN article [Service Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx).

The relevant right is

> READ_CONTROL  Required to call the QueryServiceObjectSecurity function to query the security descriptor of the service object.

The call to CreateService returns a handle with the access rights indicated by the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter, which you've set to

```
SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG | 
  SERVICE_START | 
  SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | 
  SERVICE_INTERROGATE
```

That gives the handle the right to change the service configuration, to start the service, query the service's status and interrogate the service - but not the right to query the security descriptor.

Add `READ_CONTROL` to `dwDesiredAccess` and the problem will go away.  Better still, set `dwDesiredAccess` to `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS`.

Comment: Johnson , arx , thanks for the reply. Adding READ_CONTROL  does not solve the problem, however if i set SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS makes problem go away, but that does not makes sense as READ_CONTROL should be able to fix this what am i missing here? i do not want to add extra access to handle if its really not required.

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  (It doesn't really hurt for the handle to have full rights, though.)

Comment: I found the problem, i was making another call right after QueryServiceObjectSecurity  to SetServiceObjectSecurity which required handle to have access - WRITE_DAC, adding this resolved issue. Thank you so much i really appreciate your time you put in.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [Service Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains that the access right `READ_CONTROL` is required to call `QueryServiceObjectSecurity`.

In the call to `CreateService` add `READ_CONTROL` to the list of access rights you request for the handle.